# Which distribution satisfy expectation of square root of summing of square of coefficients is equal to summing coefficients?

Tags: probability, expectation

Draw $C_1$, $C_2$, ... $C_n$ from some distribution, for any $\lambda_i>0$, we hope to get
\begin{equation}
 \underset {C_1,C_2,\cdots, C_n}{\mathbb{E} } \left[ \sqrt{\lambda_1^2 C_1+ \lambda_2^2 C_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n^2 C_n} \right] = \Theta(\lambda_1+ \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n)
\end{equation}

Are there distribution making the above inequality holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the distribution is supported on $[0,\eta]$, the expected value  is less than 
$$\sqrt{\eta}\sqrt{\lambda_1^2+\ldots+\lambda_n^2} \leq \sqrt{\eta}\,(\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n).\tag{1}$$
A similar inequality holds if the distribution is supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and has a finite expected value, in virtue of [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting). The converse inequality is more delicate. For sure the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives:
$$\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\lambda_1^2 C_1+\ldots+\lambda_n^2 C_n}\geq \lambda_1\sqrt{C_1}+\ldots+\lambda_n\sqrt{C_n},\tag{2}$$
hence a sufficient condition for the converse inequality to hold is that our distribution is supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and has a finite expected value for $\sqrt{x}$.